# How to choses coordinate systems and change between them?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, coordinate-systems

I understand that when choosing a system for the problem that interests me I need to consider all the things that effect what I want to calculate and try to pick the thing that fits my interests the most, the answer I get will depend on my choice, for example the velocity of an object, if I am considering the velocity of a car from the point of view of another car then its velocity would be the first car velocity - the second car velocity in respect to the first car for direction, if I am looking at a mass on car from outside the velocity of the mass would be the cars velocity where as from inside the cars system the mass velocity is 0  considering it was at rest , yet going through more complicated systems it is getting more complicated to chose a system and to identify the velocities correctly and changing between them without getting lost , same thing for figuring out what systems have momentum and energy conservation or if my system does achieve such conditions or not

and some orientation regarding polar spherical and cartesian would be nice too, I mostly go to cartesian for thing I am used to , if we are looking at a ball then it would be appropriate to use spherical .

I know that all the above can be developed mostly by experimenting and solving a lot of problems and I will certainly work towards understanding them but such requiring problems make me sure of an underlying problem

Comment: Again you have a post consisting of a single run on sentence making it difficult to understand

Comment: For the equations of motion to work, always choose an inertial frame to measure quantities in. You also have a choice of orientations, and you have to make sure all quantities are expressed in the same orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that one must choose coordinates in a way that is specific to the problem at hand, however, this is indeed a non-trivial task and is part of the art of problem solving. Richard Feynman stated that one of the things he could not teach his students was problem solving. He could teach them how to compute certain quantities, but he could not teach one problem solving, to him this was a skill that hopefully could be developed. In some respects, choosing coordinates is a lot like this, it is a skill which is developed through practice. There are some general guidelines, however. Look for *symmetry*, if the problem exhibits a symmetry like polar, azimuthal, spherical, cylindrical, or other geometric symmetry properties, then choose the respective coordinate system; this will generally simplify the problem greatly. When you are working from the Lagrangian point of view, you will want to identify the *configuration manifold* associated with the problem and then choose the coordinates that reflects the symmetries inherent in the system.

Comment: thanks and do you have an advice regarding variables properties depending on the system like relative velocity ?

Comment: @lodo The above advice applies, e.g. if you want to know about relative velocity of a car and a ball, just use cartesian coordinates. If, however, you want to know the relative velocity of an ant and a beetle crawling on the surface of a ball, use 2 dimensional curvilinear coordinates, i.e. spherical coordinates with the radial variable set to the radius of the ball.

Comment: what an interesting example I think I mostly know what problem I am facing we are learning a lot of concepts but hardly applying any so it feels like even if I understand an idea I am hardly scratching the surface at least I am starting to identify what's going on thank u for this interesting example

Comment: @lodo Yes, I know the feeling! My advice is to work out as many problems as you can, the more you push your self to apply your knowledge, the more you will learn and the better you will become at problem solving.

Comment: I appreciate this  a lot , I will try to make time to solve problems in the subject before we Did deeper than what we already did  and hopefully it works out .